# nftables priority filter: what does this mean?

Tags: nftables, filter, priority

The nftables wiki explains the priorities [here](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Configuring_chains). Clearly, the priority is a numeric value like -10, 0 or 10. The Red Hat nftables documentation does the same.

Priorities remain numeric in the examples in the pages that follow. But in other places, like [here](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Output_text_modifiers), the numeric priority becomes an apparently meaningless `filter`, as in the following example:

```
% nft list ruleset
table inet filter {

chain input {
    type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
```

I more or less understand that the numeric priority is used to *configure* rules while the example above is the result of `nft list ruleset`. But why doesn't this output show the *configured numeric* value, but rather a meaningless (?) `filter`? And what is the value of `filter` then?

Answer (score 0):

By some luck, I think I can mostly answer my own question. The [Output text modifiers](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Output_text_modifiers) page has an option `-y` to `Print chain priority numerically.`
A bit oddly, apparently it does not by default.

With this we have:

```
# nft -y list ruleset
table inet filter {
    chain input {
            type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
```

The output is now numeric. The value `priority 0` seems to be the default value for a chain of type `filter`, based on the information provided in [the Base Chain Priotity](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php?title=Configuring_chains&oldid=208#Base_chain_priority).

Furthermore, it looks like `priority` *must be* `filter`, or possibly another predefined word (but I could not find a reference to what is allowed here.) Another word like `test` gives an error.